# to fiddle while Rome burns

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation

I only want to find if there is an equivalent to the above phrase in Latin. I am aware of the history and origin of the phrase and what instrument Nero was playing and what he was doing at the time and whether the whole story is in any case fictional.
In English the phrase ‘fiddling while Rome burns’ is used to criticise someone who is doing something trivial or irresponsible in the face of an emergency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to find an equivalent for this proverb not just in Latin but in modern European languages as well, which I think is down to the proverb's peculiar genesis. In fact, I've found only two equivalents, the French [“se moquer/ficher/foutre de tout comme de l'an 40](https://www.lalibre.be/lifestyle/magazine/2012/06/27/dou-vient-lexpression-sen-moquer-comme-de-lan-quarante-ETVR5R7UEVFFZHFBBSDWINBX7A/) (lit. “to laugh at/not give a damn about every/anything like it's year 40”, see the link for possible origins), and the Russian *пир во вре́мя чумы́* ('a feast during the plague), which is a proverbialised title of a drama by Pushkin and so closely resembles the English both in its origin and its meaning.

For Latin, I mainly consulted Erasmus' famous collection of proverbs, [arranged by topic](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Liminaria/ind_2.html) on the excellent website IHRIM. I've had several good looks at the list but haven't been able to find an exact equivalent.

- The most relevant section is [INTEMPESTIVA ET INEPTA](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Liminaria/ind_4.html#loc_210), but I only find one vaguely equivalent proverb there, ***Simulāre cupressum*** ('to be painting a cypress'), which is about doing the only thing you know how to do well even though something else is required by the circumstances. For what it's worth, it's likewise about an artistic activity.
- [ABSURDA, INDECORA, SEU PRAEPOSTERA](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Liminaria/ind_4.html#loc_69) and [INANIS OPERA](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Liminaria/ind_4.html#loc_70) showcase Latin's staggering selection of expressions for mocking people's ineptness and lack of foresight (ah the famed Roman practicality!). The general drift of these is different from what we're looking for, but you might just find something useful there.
- [CONTEMPTUS ET VILITATIS](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Liminaria/ind_4.html#loc_98) offers another massive selection of expressions for not giving a damn, but most of these seem to be too pointed.

  - Especially useful are the non-proverbial ones including *sūsque dēque ferre,* and all those *nōn floccī, naucī, pilī, nihilī pendēre/facere.*
- Another proverb of interest is [*In dexteram/utramvīs aurem dormīre*](http://ihrim.huma-num.fr/nmh/Erasmus/Proverbia/Adagium_719.html) ('to sleep on the right/either ear'), which was apparently a very common expression of total, assured security or, in turn, carelessness.

Next, here are the only two proverbs not found there but that I knew or had written down:

- *reduviam cūrāre* 'to be treating a hangnail' [is used quasi-proverbially by Cicero](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/474/2/29/2640-2648#29) to mean 'to be of little help, to be doing too little', but this implies an earnest effort, in contrast to the English expression.
- *Dum Rōmae cōnsulitur, Saguntum expugnātur* 'while they're consulting at Rome, Saguntum is being taken' – this one has the distinction of likewise dealing with a city-wide emergency and even involves Rome, but the actual vice that is being commented on here is **indecision in the face of an emergency,** and not acting with incongruous levity.

---

It's not impossible to translate the English proverb with an in effect learnèd, literary reference to [Suetonius](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1348/1/177/2468-2476#177) or [Tacitus](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1351/5/650/709-717#650), who are our first sources for the incident. But such non-idiomatic reference by itself won't express the personal judgement of triviality and irresponsibility, and is likely instead to suggest nefariousness and ill intent; in short, it will be up to the addressee to interpret.

As a bonus, here's two Jesuit epigrams on the subject: [one](https://books.google.com/books?id=05gNBsAu6JYC&pg=PA17) by Emmanuele Tesauro (1637) and [another](https://books.google.com/books?id=ExZcAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA22) by Carlo d'Aquino (1701).

Comment: me valde delectant epigrammata duorum Jesuitarum!

Comment: pergratum est responsum tuum ad rogatum meum, mi Scytha, quod quidem perfectum est et ex more tuo penitus edissertum. tibi excuso longam, ut videtur, tardationem responsi mei sed nuperrime e valetudinario dismissus sum ubi subeunda totius genus renovatio ac reformatio. magnos movit mihi scalpellum dolores, etiam maiores movet recreatio. minime efficacia sunt anodyna, exeritationes molestae. sed ne putes me in memoriam reducere Ovidium in Ponto exsulantem, sicut Catullus obdurabo. –

Comment: @JonathanHadfield Salvus sīs mī Jōhannē! hoc dīcō tam et sī legō tē haud optimā salūte fruī. quod utinam secus esset – pauca enim in vītā magis fēlīcitātī officiunt quam mala valētūdō. optumē tamen narrās tē dē valētūdināriō dīmissum et nunc recreātiōnem subīre, quamquam nōn sine molestiā. namque ad meliōrem val-nem nunc scīs tē contendere, quā spē nīsus animum rōborāre potes et recreāre, quod ut opīnor maxumum·st. Catullī exemplum bene memorās sed eundem tibi superandum prōpōnō. nam ego dolōrem nōn modo obdūrandum putō sed ei plānē medium unguem ostendendum – sī vērus nōn crēditur nōn nocēbit

Comment: maximas tibi gratias, mi Scytha! dehinc dolori numquam desinam impudicum ostendere digitum donec prorsus convaluero!